# CSS Grid automatically adding a ::before element

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-grid

I am new to CSS in general and trying out a simple grid layout. This is what I have.

CSS

```
.layoutGrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-rows: minMax(100px, auto);
}

.articleCard {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 300px 100px;
    grid-template-areas: "article-title"
                         "article-body"
                         "article-footer";
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

.articleHeader {
    grid-area: article-title;
}

.articleBody {
    grid-area: article-body;
}

.articleFooter {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 0.5fr;
    grid-template-areas: "articleDomain articleKeypoints";
    grid-area: article-footer;
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

.articleKeypoints {
    grid-area: article-keypoints;
}

.articleDomain {
    grid-area: article-domain;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .layoutGrid {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .layoutGrid {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="mainContent" className="container layoutGrid">
        <Card className={"articleCard"} style={{height:"500px", flex: "1 1 auto", padding: "1.25rem", boxSizing: "border-box"}}>

            <CardHeader className="articleHeader">
                <CardTitle>{props.articleDetails.Title}</CardTitle>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody className="articleBody">
                <CardText>{props.articleDetails.Summary}</CardText>
            </CardBody>
            <div className="row articleFooter">
                <div className="col-auto mr-auto">
                    <Button outline color="info">Read Keypoints</Button>
                </div>
                <div className="col-auto">
                    <CardSubtitle style={{verticalAlign: 'text-bottom'}}>
                        <small>{props.articleDetails.Domain}</small>
                    </CardSubtitle>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Card>
    </div>
```

There is nothing here which adds a ::before element, but in the result the first element of the grid is always a ::before element. Even the inner grid which says "Read Keypoints" has the same issue. The outer layout is in a loop but I dont think that would affect anything.

[image]

Can anyone tell how do I get around this, and also any pointers on how to improve the overall structure of the layout would be really appreciated!

Comment: I think that it is browser's default behavior because everything should has something before it!

Comment: @SaidbakR I see, how do I fix it?

Comment: It's not default behaviour of the browser to do that. If anything it would be React's doing but I doubt that as wel. If you took your screenshot a bit more to the right in the inspect element, we would probably see the causing selector. If you can't get around it, just set it to `display:none` using your own css.

Comment: @René its the container part of it. and the display is set as table in that. Heres the snippet https://imgur.com/a/BILgA

Comment: That's bootstrap.css its .container selector that adds the before and after. If you're using grid you should either not user the class `container` here (some other name) or not use bootstrap.

Comment: @René Oh! I see. That fixed the issue as well. Thanks! If you don't mind are there any other issues with the CSS i wrote?

Comment: From what I can see here you use decent indenting and pretty much stick to the same naming conventions(camelCase) for what you wrote. That's a very good start if you ask me, the rest is just a lot of practice, learning and experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing my comment as an answer as it seems to do the trick.

> That's bootstrap.css its `.container` selector that adds the before and
>   after. If you're using grid you should either not user the class
>   container here (some other name) or not use bootstrap.

Answer (score -2):

There is nothing wrong with `::before` or `::after`. Those are CSS pseudo elements/selectors that inserts something before/after the content of each selected element(s).

Here they are shown because of viewing the code dynamically in Developers tool of the browser.

Just compare it with the real source of the page - right click on the page and select `View page source` (the message vary in web browsers). A blank tab will appear with exact code as it was send from the server to the web browser.

Comment: I am using React so viewing source will not actually give me the source. I tried it firefox and chrome and it remained the same in both. The thing is I am not specifying before elements and anything to add there. Is it a CSS Grid thing which adds an element, and how do I solve it?

Comment: @SalmaanP Show me the code that is shown when you  display the Source code of the page.

Comment: The "real" source will never even show user defined pseudo-elements so that's not a great comparison. Especially when using something like React it hardly makes sense to do. It will only show the server-rendered HTML